# Camera not working iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, camera

My camera is not working, it just shows a black screen when I turn it on. Snapchat and instagram cameras aren't working as well.
In the restrictions the camera app was not restricted and still it's not working.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Perhaps your camera needs to be repaired?

Answer (score 1):

If the affected apps have permission to use the camera, try to force the iPhone to restart: hold down the Home Button and the Power Button at the same time until you see the Apple logo (about 10 seconds).

Comment: But it still is not working. The camera isn't blocked or anything. Also, in the restrictions, it's not off or anything

Comment: Uhm ... another solution is to reset iPhone settings (data and media will not be deleted). Go to Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset All Settings.      
If this doesn't go either, or it's a hardware issue or you have to restore the iPhone, so first make a good backup of everything.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reset your iphone and restore it from a backup or you could go to the store to see if they can do anything. It seems as if your Camera might be broken. If you have any insurance plan like apple care, they should probably replace your phone for you.